# sorting variable multidimensional arrays

Tags: c#, linq

I have the array of integers: d[]. for example(7 columns and some rows):

4 1 8 0 3 2 6

7 0 4 9 1 1 5

0 6 1 3 5 2 0

and so on. 
At compile time I do not know how many columns has array d. And I do not know at compile time which columns to use to orderby.

For example need to sort by: d[5], d[2], d[0], d[3]. 
But at run time I know order of the columns to sort. 
For example column indexes: 5, 2, 0, 3 which mean d[5], d[2], d[0], d[3] columns. 
How can I orderby array d using this indexes of columns?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using a jagged array (`int[][]`), then you can use LINQ by combining `OrderBy` and `ThenBy`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int[][] data = {
          new[]{4,1,8,0,3,2,6},
          new[]{7,0,4,9,1,1,5},
          new[]{0,6,1,3,5,2,0}};
        int[] sortCols = { 5, 2, 0, 3 };

        IEnumerable<int[]> qry = data;
        if (sortCols.Length > 0)
        {
            IOrderedEnumerable<int[]> sorted =
                qry.OrderBy(row => row[sortCols[0]]);
            for (int i = 1; i < sortCols.Length; i++)
            {
                int col = sortCols[i]; // for capture
                sorted = sorted.ThenBy(row => row[col]);
            }
            qry = sorted;
        }

        // show results (does actual sort when we enumerate)
        foreach (int[] row in qry)
        {
            foreach (int cell in row)
            {
                Console.Write(cell);
                Console.Write('\t');
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

You could also (alternatively) build a comparison to pass to `Array.Sort`.

Comment: I updated your answer to have the for loop start at 1 instead of 0. Otherwise you order by the first column twice, which doesn't add a lot of extra functionality ;)

Comment: @rwwilden - thanks; I switched approach half way through, and forgot to fix that bit; cheers.

Comment: Marc, rwwilden - thank you very much. That is exactly what I wanted.
I think I get stuck with OrderBy and forgot about ThenBy.
Problem solved.

Comment: @Marc: Nice solution. Wouldn't a datatable be a clean solution here?
By clean, I mean readable & easy to understand? Your opinion matters.

Comment: shahkalpesh: I'm worry about efficiency. The rank and indices in this multidimensional array can be very big. It is interesting which way in this case is faster: LINQ, SQL or C#?

Comment: DataTable != SQL; I don't think anyone is suggesting pushing the data down to a db just to sort it. "faster" would need profiling - but note that DataTable is actually arranged by column (not by row), so sorting *might* be more expensive with a DataTable (untested, but makes sense). I would expect the Array.Sort and LINQ approaches to be similar, with LINQ "good enough" to be worth the extra simplicity.

Comment: Way this doesn't work:

IOrderedEnumerable<uint[]> sorted = 
       from row in qry 
       from col in sortCols 
       orderby row[col] 
       select row; 

It is not sorting but mixing up data.

Comment: Can you clarify how you are using that? In particular, the query syntax usage (from ... select) won't allow you to append sorts (ThenBy) at runtime; I expect this is part of the issue, but I'd need to see how you are trying to use it to be sure.

Comment: Marc: I was trying to use OrderBy only without ThenBy. In a regular way it is posible to put a sequence of items to sort by: OrderBy row.Name, row.LastName,...
I am trying to find out how to dynamically list this sequence to OrderBy. This query doesn't give a error but it doesn't work:
IOrderedEnumerable<uint[]> sorted = 
from row in qry 
from col in sortCols 
orderby row[col] 
select row;

Comment: Query syntax will work, but not for a dynamic number of columns - you need to ThenBy the subsequent columns. The "orderby row[col] select row" should work fine for a *single* sort, though - is it not? Or are you seeing some error?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using DataTable to create a column structure at runtime & adding rows.
And then sort it using Column's name.

e.g. DataTable.Sort = "Column5 ASC, Column2 ASC" (pseudocode).

Comment: Thanks for an answer. I'll do it if there is no LINQ solution.
But I guess the LINQ was invented exactly to replace the DataTable and so on. Any LINQ/C# idea?

Comment: @lldar - LINQ doesn't really *replace* DataTable; they have different use-cases, and can be used in combination if you want.